# title of the page repeats twice in compiled pdf

Tags: header-footer

I have a latex file, and after compiling, the title is repeats twice in every second page. 
The compiled file looks like this:

On top, the sentence Detection of nnnnnnn mmmm uuuuu
tttt wwww-aaaaa is repeated twice and has gone into each other.

[image]

To compile, I do the following:

```
latex 1.tex
dvipdfmx 1.dvi
evince 1.pdf
```

The original file, 1.tex has the following code

```
   \documentclass[12pt]{book}

\begin{document}
  \include{2}

\end{document}
```

Then there is the file 2.tex

```
\chapter{Detection of nnnnnnn mmmm uuuuu tttt wwww-aaaaa} % Write in your own chapter title

\label{Chapter6}

\lhead{Chapter 6. \emph{Detection of nnnnnnn mmmm uuuuu tttt wwww-aaaaa}} % Write in your own chapter title to set the page header

\section{Introduction}


XXXXXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXXXXX







XXXXXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: delete the `\lhead` command

Comment: please see the comments on your previous question about making a minimal example, you could delete almost all the packages and replace `\include{2}` by the contents of that file to make a small single file example that people can easily test.

Comment: Thank you so much David. You solved this problem too. I was on the way to minimize it when you actually solved the problem :X

Comment: hard to imagine how it came to be there, hopefully theer is no tutorial documentation suggesting using `\lhead` with explicit numbers like that?

Comment: Actually it is a template I am using. So I guess it has been there.

Comment: That's what I suspected but if it is in the template report it as a bug to whoever provided the template.

Comment: Where can we find the template?

Comment: Hi Johannes, I need to ask the friend who provided it to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The heading is duplicated in the output as you have duplicated it in the input, delete the `\lhead` command which is never intended to be used in the document body.  Headings are automatically determined from the section titles using the code you have specified in the preamble.